# getrawtransaction in Bitcoin-Qt (0.8.5)

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, json-rpc, raw-transaction

I am getting an error {"code"=>-5, "message"=>"No information available about transaction"} when issuing `getrawtransaction`.

I am aware that

> since bitcoind/Bitcoin-qt 0.8, no transaction index is kept anymore by
>   default, as it is not necessary for validation in the new database
>   model.

( Discussed here: [getrawtransaction error? [Code -5]](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9147/getrawtransaction-error-code-5/9152#9152) )

I have followed the answers and rebuilt my index with --reindex. I also have txindex=1 specified in my Bitcoin.conf file.

I am still getting the same error every time. What could be the issue? How do I make sure the client keeps an updated index along with synchronising for new blocks?

**UPDATE:** I tried working with a random hash: "d3ad39fa52a89997ac7381c95eeffeaf40b66af7a57e9eba144be0a175a12b11" and it works. Not for all though. Is transaction data specific only to some blocks?

Comment: Which transaction data can't you reach? I know that genesis block coinbase transaction is not fetchable, since it is not really a valid, spendable transaction - https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3303

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that getrawtransaction only works on utxo transactions which means outputs of that transactions are not spent and still kept index by the bitcoin client.